# How to override admin notification toolbar?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, template, adminnotification

I am currently using a extension and i would like to add some codes to it to override the notification bar that usually shows up under the header. based on my checks, the file that displays this is...

> /design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml

i tried adding the following code to my extension's layout xml file but it didn't work!

```
<reference name="notifications">
<action method="setTemplate">
<template>extension-folder/notification/toolbar.phtml</template>
</action>
</reference>
```

i checked adminnotification.xml file and i realized it had this code:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="notifications">
            <block type="adminhtml/notification_toolbar" name="notification_toolbar" as="notification_toolbar" acl="system/adminnotification/show_toolbar" template="notification/toolbar.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="notifications">
            <block type="adminhtml/notification_window" name="notification_window" as="notification_window" acl="system/adminnotification/show_toolbar" template="notification/window.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

so i decided to copy this section:

```
<reference name="notifications">
            <block type="adminhtml/notification_toolbar" name="notification_toolbar" as="notification_toolbar" acl="system/adminnotification/show_toolbar" template="notification/toolbar.phtml" />
        </reference>
```

and paste it in my extension's xml file and modify the template section with my modified template location. This worked, displaying my modified notification toolbar, but somehow was now displaying 2 instances of it and i cant figure out why!

can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, i figured out what i was doing wrong!

the reference name i was using was incorrect. instead of using `notifications` i should have used `notification_toolbar`

if you look at the codes i posted for adminnotification.xml, there are 2 blocks under the same reference name. by using the block name instead, this tells the xml the specific block i'm trying to override, which solves the problem!